# Why isn't the child pom picking the right profile?

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

I've stripped down this project to be as simple as possible. I'm using the [maven-echo-plugin](https://github.com/khmarbaise/echo-maven-plugin)<sup>1</sup>. All this project does is to echo a particular statement depending whether or not the `deluxe` profile is active. If I am not using the deluxe profile, the project prints out `This is the base configuration`. If I am using the deluxe profile, the project prints out `This is the deluxe configuration`.

I have the following parent pom:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>name.weintraub</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>deluxe</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>deluxe</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-echo-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>echo</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>validate</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <echos>
                                        <echo>This is the deluxe configuration</echo>
                                    </echos>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-echo-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>echo</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <echos>
                                <echo>This is the base configuration</echo>
                            </echos>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If I run:

```
$ mvn validate
```

This will print out `This is the base configuration`.

If I run:

$ mvn -Pdeluxe validate

This will print out `This is the deluxe configuration`

So far so good:

I now create a child pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <deluxe>true</deluxe>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>name.weintraub</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>name.weintraub</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</project>
```

Note that I've set the property `deluxe` to `true` in the beginning of the pom.

When I run:

```
$ mvn validate
```

It prints out `This is the base configuration`.

If I run it like this:

```
mvn -Ddeluxe=true validate
```

It then prints `This is the deluxe configuration`. If I do

```
mvn -Pdeluxe validate
```

It prints out `This is the deluxe configuration`.

So, I can see that the child pom is picking up the parent profiles, and if I activate the profile on the command line either directly, or by using a property. However, even though I set the property in the pom itself, my project doesn't seem to pick  up the parent's profile.

Why?

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm using version 0.1 because that's the latest version in Maven Central, and this it was called `maven-echo-plugin` back in version 1.0. The documentation otherwise is the same.

Comment: First there is a newer version of the [echo-maven-plugin](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.soebes.maven.plugins%22%20AND%20a%3A%22echo-maven-plugin%22) cause it had to be renamed...If you set the property in the child the parent has already been read and analysed and the profiles have been activated or not...

Comment: BTW: What is the idea behind the question? What kind of issue would you like to solve with this profile?

Comment: @khmarbaise  Yes I know that the plugin has been renamed, but I couldn't find the later versions in Maven Central and figured that the older version is good enough for this purpose.

Comment: @khmarbaise  The purpose? We use a company Pom to set various standards we want to enforce and to make it easier for our developers. For example, the corporate Pom defines all of the site reports. We have a few projects that need an older source and target java versions. If I could do this via profiles,  the developers merely have to set the property in their Pom, and everything is taken care of. However,  it's not working and I have no idea why. Is it a Maven concept I don't understand or am I doing something not right, or is this a bug?

Comment: @khmarbaise This Pom is merely a test to understand how profiles work. It's the simplest project I could create to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Profiles can *only* be activated using system properties (i.e. commandline) / environment variables as well as JDK and OS, not by using pom properties. (see [Introduction to Build Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html): "Currently, this detection is limited to prefix-matching of the JDK version, the presence of a system property or the value of a system property.")

So, your approach can't work that way. You might want to take a look at asymmetric profiles as an alternative.

Comment: Okay dumb question: What exactly is a system property vs. a property? When I set a property in the `pom.xml`, that's not considered a system property?

Comment: System properties are the ones provided by the JVM, such as user.home and the properties defined directly on the command line (via -D). Properties defined in the pom are only simple / non-system properties. One reason for this distinction lies in the fact that profiles are selected early in the building of the model, where properties are not yet available. Model interpolation (i.e. resolving of properties comes later).

Comment: This also doesn't seem to work using file activation either. Ends up that the `<source>` and `<target>` in my `maven-compiler-plugin` in my parent pom uses `${javac.source}` and `${javac.target}` which are defined as `1.7` by default. I can set these values in the child pom, and it works without having to create a profile. I'm just doing it that way.